Redefine default value of attribute from items.xml
I need to modify the definition of an itemtype, in particular, I need to modify only the default value of an attribute of the type.
The type is the AbstractOrder and the attribute is the paymentType.
In b2bacceleratorservices-items.xml, the AbstractOrder has the attribute paymentType
<attribute qualifier="paymentType" type="CheckoutPaymentType">
    <description>Payment type for Checkout summary</description>
    <persistence type="property"/>
    <defaultvalue>em().getEnumerationValue("CheckoutPaymentType","CARD")</defaultvalue>
</attribute>

My intention is to modify the value to "ACCOUNT" like below
<attribute qualifier="paymentType" type="CheckoutPaymentType">
    <description>Payment type for Checkout summary</description>
    <persistence type="property" />
    <defaultvalue>em().getEnumerationValue("CheckoutPaymentType","ACCOUNT")</defaultvalue>
</attribute>

So, no big change, no redefinition of the type of attribute or other esoteric stuff. I tried to modify the attribute and the result is that on the build there is the error:
BUILD FAILED
/home//git/sole/core-customize/hybris/bin/platform/build.xml:13: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home//git/sole/core-customize/hybris/bin/platform/resources/ant/compiling.xml:93: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home//git/sole/core-customize/hybris/bin/platform/resources/ant/antmacros.xml:584: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home//git/sole/core-customize/hybris/bin/platform/resources/ant/antmacros.xml:587: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot merge namespace ((sole)) into ((<merged>)) due to duplicate attribute 'AbstractOrder.paymentType(CheckoutPaymentType):((sole))::YAttributeDescriptor[sole-items.xml:438(AttributeTagListener)][null]' vs 'AbstractOrder.paymentType(CheckoutPaymentType):((b2bacceleratorservices))::YAttributeDescriptor[b2bacceleratorservices-items.xml:233(AttributeTagListener)][PROPERTY]'
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.typesystem.YNamespace.mergeNamespace(YNamespace.java:326)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.typesystem.YTypeSystem.mergeNamespaces(YTypeSystem.java:74)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.typesystem.YTypeSystem.finalizeTypeSystem(YTypeSystem.java:65)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.typesystem.YTypeSystemLoader.finish(YTypeSystemLoader.java:592)

Is there any way to reach my goal using items.xml, or is the only way to modify the default value from Java code?

You need to use redeclare attribute for the field to override it.
<attribute qualifier="paymentType" type="CheckoutPaymentType" redeclare="true">
    <description>Payment type for Checkout summary</description>
    <persistence type="property" />
    <defaultvalue>em().getEnumerationValue("CheckoutPaymentType","ACCOUNT")</defaultvalue>
</attribute>


I tried it, doesn't work

Did you get an error or it was just not functional?

the error was the same, always on build (ant clean all) phase. From documentation (https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/8bffa9cc86691014bb70ac2d012708bc.html?locale=en-US&version=2005#adding-types-and-attributes), the redeclare property can be used on an attribute of an itemtype that extend an item that have an attribute with the same name. I think that it is impossible modify an attribute of the same itemtype; it's possible add new attribute but not modify the attribute defined on the perent extension
